# jQuery scroll from button to section problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a problem with my jQuery. 
I want to scroll my site by clicking button with class "my-name" in my header:

```
<header>
  <button class="my-name"></button>
</header>
```

to a

```
<section class="about"></section>
```

I gave position relative to both header and section, and put height: 100vh;

this is my jQuery code:

```
const $nameBtn = $(".my-name");
const $about = $(".about").offset().top;

$nameBtn.on("click", function() {
  $("body").animate(
    {
      scrollTop: $about
    },
    1000
  );
});
```

I've tried using console.log to see if my code works, and it should.
I see my variables.
I've also tried using id's not classes, but it didn't make a difference.

I'm just starting with jQuery, do you have some ideas, why it doesn't wokr?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
$("html, body").animate({
  scrollTop: $about
},1000);
```

You need to use `$('html, body')`. You need to use both `html` and `body` to ensure compatibility with some browsers because some browsers set scrollTop on `body`, while others set it on `html`